# Any Immediate Pane in xcode like Visual Studio or VBA?

Tags: xcode, debugging, testing

Is there an immediate pane in xcode like so in visual studio or in VBA?

For example, when in VBA I can test some code in immediate pane quite fast, but seems impossible in xcode without running the project.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The nearest equivalent for Swift code in Xcode 6 is [Playgrounds](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_6_0.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How about object-c? As far as i know, it cannot be used for object-c